# No backend data is publishing from fullcalendar in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, fullcalendar

I am attempting to use the [fullcalendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fullcalendar/core) package with Django for calendar implementation. I am able to display the calendar, create and save a model to the database, but I am having issues bringing it into the template. I can bring in context event information, **as for bringing it onto the *actual calendar*, I am missing the target and hitting a wall**. My belief is how I am calling on the URL to bring back the JSON response data. All assistance is appreciated

**models.py**

```
class CalendarEvents(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=EVENT_CHOICES)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=145,null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**urls.py**

```
path("calendar", view=apps_calendar_view, name="calendar"),
path('calendar/all_events/', view=apps_calendar_all_events, name='calendar.all_events'),
```

**views.py**

```
def apps_calendar_view(request):
    all_events = CalendarEvents.objects.all()
    context = {
        "events":all_events,
    }
    return render(request,'apps/apps-calendar.html', context)

def apps_calendar_all_events(request):
    all_events = CalendarEvents.objects.all()
    out = []
    for event in all_events:
        out.append({
        'type':event.type,
        'title': event.name,
        'location':event.location,
        'id': event.id,
        'start': event.start.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"),
        'end': event.end.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"),
        })
    print(out)
    return JsonResponse(out, safe=False)
```

**apps-calendar.html**

```
    <div class="col-xl-9">
        <div class="card card-h-100">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div id="calendar">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
    import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core'
    import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'

    const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar')
    const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [
        dayGridPlugin
        // any other plugins
    ],
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    weekends: false,
    events: [
        '/calendar/all_events'
    ]
    })

    calendar.render()
</script>
```

From this image, I am able to load the basic `fullcalendar` and get some sample data on the calendar (sample data from preload .init.js), however *my object events* won't publish. My event context printed at #1, not showing at #2; only sample data is

[image: fullcalendar no backend data]

Here is the JSON output from `apps_calendar_all_events` that I want to land on the calendar. Ideally would be at #2 from image above.

```
[{"type": "Success", "title": "Satelite Network Install", "description": "New Network Install", "location": null, "id": 1, "start": "07/30/2023, 12:00:00", "end": "07/31/2023, 12:00:00"}]
```

[image: apps_calendar_all_events views.py output]

Comment: Please provide your sample JSON output data as _text_, then we can examine it properly, potentially re-use it in a demonstration, etc. None of that can easily be done from a picture. You can [edit] your post. Thanks

Comment: Having said that, at a glance I can see that the dates you're outputting are not in a format fullCalendar will recognise. Please read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-parsing

Comment: Thanks for that addition, I will stray from picture outputs and add them as text. With your latest point, I am going to try and change the date output. Do you know if there is a preferential model type from Django? I am using `models.DateTimeField` and that format is autointerpreted

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about django specifically, but I would be surprised if its date formatting options were not well documented